# what does GetComponent[?, ProjectedExtent]: (? => TilerKeyMethods[K, K2]) and SpatialComponent: Boundable mean?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, geotrellis

```
def fromRdd[
    K: GetComponent[?, ProjectedExtent]: (? => TilerKeyMethods[K, K2]),
    V <: CellGrid,
    K2: SpatialComponent: Boundable
  ](rdd: RDD[(K, V)],  scheme: ZoomedLayoutScheme):
    (Int, TileLayerMetadata[K2]) =
      _fromRdd[K, V, K2](rdd, scheme, None)
```

In the definition of FromRdd, I couldn't undetstand K, V and K2. I know they are both implicit parameters. but what does  GetComponent[?, ProjectedExtent]: (? => TilerKeyMethods[K, K2]) and SpatialComponent: Boundable mean? Anyone could do me a favor? Thank a lot.

Comment: sorry not implicit parameters, but the generic type

Answer (score 0):

Such expressions are called [Context Bounds](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/context-bounds.html).

- `GetComponent` is just a lens type class, that in this particular case means that type `K` has a function that allows us to *get* `ProjectedExtent` from this `K` typed object.
- `TilerKeyMethods` is a type class that allows to [transform](https://github.com/locationtech/geotrellis/blob/master/spark/src/main/scala/geotrellis/spark/tiling/TilerKeyMethods.scala#L23) between `ProjectedExtent` keys and layout keys.
- `SpatialComponent` and `TemporalComponent` are two type aliases for the two lens types: `Component[K, SpatialKey]` and `Component[K, TemporalKey]`
- `Boundable` is a type class with comparison functions.

Let me know if that's enough for you, also you can always post questions in our GeoTrellis gitter channel. I strognly recommend you to walk through [GeoTrellis docs](https://geotrellis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/core-concepts.html?highlight=SpatialComponent) and to get familiar with Scala language concepts to understand this code better.